# How to import external iOS framework in flutter plugin?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm doing a **flutter plugin** for stream video by using **RTSP protocol**. I had no problem develop it for Android, but in iOS things are more complex. I have to use an **external library ([SGPlayer](https://github.com/libobjc/SGPlayer))** for getting the player work. I also downloaded the demo that uses this library and **seems to work**. This library **is NOT on Cocoapods** and I need to import it directly into the plugin project from my file system. the downloaded and compiled file structure of the plugin that I would like to use looks like this:

[image: External library file structure]

My problem is **adding the ".framework" extension file correctly to the iOS project** in a way that I can use it to develop the flutter plugin (iOS part).

**UPDATE:**
I built the project with the framework by using instructions at this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17978

The problem now is that while compiling the framework it change the umbrella header because, I think, it's not using the framework module.modulemap but another one. The result is that is importing just some header and implementations, and not all.

Comment: Hello, any solution to that ?

Comment: Sorry mate, I moved all parts to the main project and abandoned the idea to create a plugin. I had no time at work to find a solution on this things.

Answer (score 5):

1.Place `myFramework.framework` to iOS plugin folder `/ios ex: myPlugin/ios`

2.Update iOS plugin file: `myPlugin/ios/myPlugin.podspec`
Adding the below line at the bottom of the file, above 'end'

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'myFramework.framework'
```

In Terminal : `cd to myPlugin/example/ios`
run command

```
pod install
```

or

```
pod update
```

Now we can find the iOS plugin code by open iOS project (example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace) in XCode and go to

Answer (score 1):

@Lorenzo you can pack your plugin and make private CocoaPod or Carthage repo. 
[Here is](https://medium.com/practical-code-labs/how-to-create-private-cocoapods-in-swift-3cc199976a18) a good article howtos

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! I have a new question, at the moment, to get things works, I had to import the local framework by using the script that I found in the Github page that I had mentioned in my answer update. The problem is that I had to remove the `use_frameworks!` from the Podfile and now is impossible for me use Swift Pod if I would like to, but if I leave it, and I try to run the app I get a lot of errors. At this point, my question is: Is possible to use Objective-c pod in a Swift plugin? and how .podspec and Podfile settings are?

Comment: Hey, but what is IDEA behind creating private CocoaPod repo? I should create private CocoaPod and how then to connect my local .framework with that CocoaPod repo?